# Proving a function is one to one

Tags: functions

How do I prove the function: $f(x,y) = 2x^2 +y$ is one to one and/or onto in $\mathbb Z\times  \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z $

I know for a fact that a function is one to one if:

$$ f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$$

and onto $$f(x)=y$$ and solving for $y$ by tranposing...

How does this apply when in $\mathbb Z \times  \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z $. I can't seem to figure out an algebraic method to solve using the defenitions above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $f$ is onto, use that $f(0,y) = y$. That should do the trick.

Furthermore, $f(0,4)=f(1,2)$, for instance. Can it still be one to one?

Comment: Okay, so in this case it cannot be one to one since they both yield the same value but are not equal. However, is trial an error (although this answer might be trivial) the method to use? Or can it be solved algebraically?

Comment: Giving a counterexample is perfectly valid and there's an abundance of those. However, if you insist: Say $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$, then $f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)=0=2(x_1^2-x_2^2)+(y_1-y_2)$. Thus, you're looking for solutions to $y_2-y_1=2(x_1^2-x_2^2)$ and I hope you can see lots of those (just choose whichever $x_1, x_2, y_1$ you like...).